# Преобразовать словарь в строку

Tags: python, dict

Есть словарь

```
d =  {  
'name': 'string',
'age': 'int',
 'gender': 'string'
}
```

Как более компактно и правильно преобразовать словарь к строке вида:

```
s = 'name string, age int, gender string'
```

Можно через replace, но может есть получше варианты

```
s = str(d).replace(':','').replace("'",'').replace('{','').replace('}','')
```

Comment: `print(', '.join(a+' '+b for a,b in d.items()))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Шаги:

- Перебор пар ключей-значений
- Составление из них строк, где ключ и значение разделяются пробелом
- Объединение пар запятой

Пример:

```
d = {
    'name': 'string',
    'age': 'int',
    'gender': 'string'
}
s = ', '.join(f'{k} {v}' for k, v in d.items())
print(s)
# name string, age int, gender string
```